# HBase - query difference between two timestamps

Tags: java, hbase, trading

I'm considering HBase as a trading system database due in part to its first-class timestamp-based versioning of rows. Trades get modified all the time, and we typically have to cope with that explicitly in the data model when working with SQL databases. In HBase, I'd model trades (not individual trade versions) as rows and let HBase do the hard work of giving me access to trade versions that were live at a previous point in time.

The query side of the system needs access to trade data in 3 major ways:

1. Current versions of all trades. This is clearly supported by HBase.
2. Versions of all trades that were active at a specific timestamp. Again, clear support from HBase. The purpose of this query is typically end of day processes that want to report the trade population at a specific time of day.
3. Activity between 2 timestamps. This is useful for feeding information at end of day to systems which are already in sync with the trading system and want to know what's change. It also forms the basis for a daily Profit and Loss (P&L) calculation which indicates what the *change* of P&L is from yesterday's daily value.

So, my question is: does HBase have any built-in support for performing a "diff" between two timestamps? Alternatively, is there any best-practice way of meeting this requirement at the database level? If not, I'd need consider building a process that fetches two timestamp-based queries out of the database and performs a difference operation.

I'd expect the output of the process to be:

- A list of trades trades at the new timestamp that have changed since the old timestamp.
- A separate list of trades as-of the old timestamp that have been made obsolete at the new timestamp.

Those pieces of information allow me to apply the positive changes and "back out" the negative changes. For example, if a trade has changed notional from 1m USD to 2m USD, I want to be able to apply a +2m change and then back out a -1m change to result in a net change of +1m for the day.

Comment: Why don't you add timestamp as part of your row key? That will help you scan across a time-range.

Comment: Row key needs to be Trade Identifier. All of the trade modification use cases need to lookup trades by their id.